# How to correctly use dotenv / .env for passing parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript, parameters, dotenv, .env

I've got a typescript app that I'm editing via VS Code.  I've removed sensitive information into a .env file:

```
# .env file
NAME='foobar'
```

In my main app, that is consuming the .env file, I have installed the dotenv npm package.  I'm also trying to pass the environment variable as parameter to a function in another file.

App.ts

```
import {
    printName
} from "./printStuff"
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

await printName(process.env.NAME)
```

printStuff.ts

```
export async function printName(name: string){
    console.log(name)
}
```

This is where the issue occurs.  I get the dreaded red squiggly lines under ***process.env.NAME*** in the app.ts

```
string | undefined
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type     'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I've been able to solve this via

```
    await printName(process.env.NAME || '')
```

but this seems off to me.  Is there a better way of doing this?
My apologies in advance, I'm new to Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a non-null assertion operator:

```
await printName(process.env.NAME!); // ok
```

but keep in mind this is just an assertion for TypeScript to tell it that it isn't `undefined`. It can still be `undefined` at runtime if you don't set the env variable and can cause issues.

Comment: Well, I've never heard of the "non-null assertion operator".  Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

Any passed in env var could possibly be undefined, therefore you either need to guarantee in your code that it exists before passing it to `printName` or make it optional in printName.

A few options could be:

```js
const name = process.env.NAME

//Check name exists before using it
if (name) {
   printName(name)
} else {
   //Add some error handling. What should happen if name doesnt exist?
}

//Alternatively, if name is undefined, do error handling
if (!name) {
   //Add some error handling. What should happen if name doesnt exist?
}
printName(name)
```

```js
//Make name optional in printName, possibly risky if you arent handling 
//  what happens if name is undefined elsewhere
export async function printName(name?: string){
    console.log(name)
}
```